# npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

I am trying to install npm package dependencies in to my angular application and i am getting this error. Any help to fix this?

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: error-ex@^1.2.0
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dilushi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T13_07_17_602Z-debug.log
```

I will attach my `package.json` file here.

```
{
  "name": "app-pfe",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
    "@ng-dynamic-forms/core": "^6.0.6",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.18.0",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "inspector": "^0.5.0",
    "jsrsasign": "^8.0.12",
    "ngx-auth": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.1.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tsickle": ">=0.25.5",
    "tslib": "^1.7.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: There are some errors going on in the npm registry. 
You can check the status here: https://status.npmjs.org/, it should be solved soon.
Don't install other packages or use other registries to patch that, you will mess things up :)

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8465

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you can see on [`https://status.npmjs.org`](https://status.npmjs.org), 4 packages are down at this moment.

They've fixed the issue but we need to wait for CDN world propagation.

Don't update your packages or install new one to fix this.

EDIT: not working yet in Europe at 14:34 UTC

Answer (score 5):

[image]

100% (solution) : npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you triggered wrong command, check spelling of the command
`npx react-native run-android` then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try configuring npm using this
`npm config set registry https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry`

Comment: How can I reset it to the default registry later?

Comment: npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: In order to switch between different .npmrc files (which can point to different registries) it is better to use npmrc tool - https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmrc
For more information check here - https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-your-registry-settings-as-an-npm-enterprise-user

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error you should run this command

> `npm init react-app my-app`

For more information check this link [npm error 404 not Found](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8465)

Answer (score 0):

There might be another reason for this issue, kindly check your npm registry config whether it is http://registry.npmjs.org/ and not http://registry.npmjs.org or https://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

check your npm g list firstly,
npm -g list
then add create-react-app as a global

```html
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app myapp
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work now. They have fixed it. I have tried it now and working

Comment: I had the same issue, after a couple of times it worked, without me changing anything.

Answer (score -1):

Some time your other packages may not compatible with the package that you are going to install via npm

> **uninstall and reinstall latest Node**

that having latest NPM version

Answer (score -1):

1. create **.npmrc**  file in your project
2. then  add @foo:registry=https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/

Answer (score -1):

Almost every developer knows npm, the JavaScript package manager very useful for faster development and for downloading the entire Internet (yes, npm has this fault…)

npm install npm@latest -g

npx create-react-app myapp

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem.
To solve I just ran npm install with the root user to fix it. Now it's working.

```
Sudo su 
npm install
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is very bad advice. If you have to use su or sudo, it indicates a problem with your permissions in that region of your file system. You should fix them in the first place instead of installing packages with root permissions.

Answer (score -3):

I also faced same problem and none of above worked for me!

To solve this issue:

1. Delete both `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files
2. Then in cmd (go to the correct path of boilerplate-express app) and then use:

   ```
   npm init -y
   ```

   It will create a new `package.json` file but in that file you must check `"main"` property, set the `"main"` property to `server.js`
3. And in `server.js` file, they used `var bGround = require('fcc-express-bground');` instead use `var bGround = require('fcc-express-background');` and save the file (because in npmjs.com there is no module such as `fcc-express-bground` but `fcc-express-background` module is available for boileplate app)
4. After that install those package modules which are asked.