# vue installation in the cmd keeps showing me deprecated request how to fix?

Tags: vue.js, npm, request, registry

I have a problem when installing vue. I uninstalled node and reinstalled it without a change but it keeps showing this error. I installed vue in cmd using `npm install -g @vue/cli`.

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'error-ex@^1.3.1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'parse-json'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hassa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T20_03_55_612Z-debug.log
```

Here are the last lines in the npm cache logs:

```
329 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for error-ex@^1.3.1 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex
330 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
331 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 6023ms
332 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex
332 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:104:15
332 verbose stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
332 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
333 verbose statusCode 404
334 verbose pkgid error-ex@^1.3.1
335 verbose cwd C:\Users\hassa
336 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
337 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@vue/cli"
338 verbose node v13.8.0
339 verbose npm  v6.13.6
340 error code E404
341 error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex
342 error 404
343 error 404 'error-ex@^1.3.1' is not in the npm registry.
344 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
345 error 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'parse-json'
346 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
347 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
348 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with `error-ex` in `npm`: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5183

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60189156/npm-err-404-not-found-get-https-registry-npmjs-org-error-ex

Comment: thank you i used vpn and it works for me

Answer (score 1):

I used vpn and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Is it preventing Vue from installing? 
If you are able to work with the project, I wouldn't worry about it.

It seems request was deprecated yesterday. I don't think there is anything you need to resolve in terms of uninstalling/reinstalling any packages.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: Yes i  can't installing vue at all , what should i do right now ?? waiting ?

Comment: The edit and cmd log definitely clarify.
Request being deprecated was just a warning and not the cause of the install failing.
Glad to hear vpn worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your terminal :)
`npm config set registry https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry`