# I have a problem installing npm in php laravel and I get this error

Tags: php, laravel, npm

When I try to install npm I get this error version 8.19.3

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/laravel-echo-server/-/laravel-echo-server-1.6.3.tgz - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'laravel-echo-server@https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/laravel-echo-server/-/laravel-echo-server-1.6.3.tgz' is not in this registry.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/common-errors#not-found--server-error May be of some help

Comment: skimdb seems to be down. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60189156/npm-err-404-not-found-get-https-registry-npmjs-org-error-ex to find out how to switch back to the main registry

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands

```
npm un laravel-echo-server

npm i laravel-echo-server
```

Answer (score 0):

That URL seems to return a 404 in general.

```bash
curl -Is  https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/laravel-echo-server/-/laravel-echo-server-1.6.3.tgz| grep HTTP | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

Possible Solutions:

- Remove & re-add it to your repo with `npm i laravel-echo-server`. If you still encounter issues,
- Add the package directly from the github URL. It is possible to have NPM directly include Public Git (Github, Bitbucket) repositories: using the same command above `npm i https://github.com/tlaverdure/Laravel-Echo-Server` [Further Reading](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/install-npm-packages-from-gitgithub)