# 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/database-debug.log - Not found When installing packages for Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

When installing packages for Firebase Cloud Functions, I get the error:
404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/database-debug.log - Not found

When checking the above URL I indeed see:
{"error":"Not found"}

I am using NodeJS version 14.20.1, npm version 9.1.3 and firebase-tools version 11.16.1.

The following is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "emulators:start": "firebase emulators:start",
    "emulators:stop": "lsof -t -i:5000 -i:5001 -i:4030 -i:9099 -i:9001 -i:9199 -i:8091 -i:9090 | xargs kill -9",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec --timeout 10000",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.6",
    "@firebase/app-compat": "^0.1.28",
    "@google-cloud/tasks": "^3.0.5",
    "@types/rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "acorn": "^8.8.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "csv-parse": "^5.2.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.1.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mocha": "^9.1.3",
    "puppeteer": "^10.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.3.5",
    "typesense": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The end of the log says:

```
2781 verbose stack HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/database-debug.log - Not found
2781 verbose stack     at /home/wpghijsen/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:95:15
2781 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
2781 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/home/wpghijsen/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:85:19)
2781 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/home/wpghijsen/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:116:23)
2781 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[nodeFromEdge] (/home/wpghijsen/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1056:19)
2781 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (/home/wpghijsen/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:926:11)
2781 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/home/wpghijsen/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:206:7)
```

I checked https://status.npmjs.org , as per [npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60189156/npm-err-404-not-found-get-https-registry-npmjs-org-error-ex) , but it shows no incidents.
It occurs to me that maybe I need a different node version, but any other suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: using: 
npm install --prefer-offline 
works, but would rather not use this option always

Comment: I turned out that npm was looking at the debug-log generated by the emulator. Deleting this file worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering as community wiki.

This was mentioned here in this github [thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12174).This is a bug in lib/outdated.js – it shouldn't be treating npm-debug.log as a package to be updated. This error will go away if you remove npm-debug.log manually from node_modules